# Error in Makefile - mingw32-make: *** [MakefileW:60: execute] Error 255

Tags: windows, bash, makefile, mpi, openmp

I'm creating a makefile to run my C programs multiple times and collect data from them. The programs need to be executed 5 times for each optimization, for every combination of input, and for each combination of the number of threads/processes in MPI and OpenMP.

The part with problems is:

```
execute:

for i in {1..5}; do \
        for pair in "100 100" "1000 10000" "20000 10000" "30000 30000" "40000 40000"; do \
            elem=$$(echo $$pair | cut -d' ' -f1); \
            size=$$(echo $$pair | cut -d' ' -f2); \
            ./src/lcs_diagonalO0.exe $$elem $$size 0; \
            ./src/lcs_diagonalO1.exe $$elem $$size 1; \
            ./src/lcs_diagonalO2.exe $$elem $$size 2; \
            ./src/lcs_diagonalO3.exe $$elem $$size 3; \
            for np in 1 2 3 4; do \
                for omp in  1 2 3 4; do \
                    mpiexec -n $$np ./src/lcs_mpiompO0.exe $$elem $$size $$omp 0; \
                    mpiexec -n $$np ./src/lcs_mpiompO1.exe $$elem $$size $$omp 1; \
                    mpiexec -n $$np ./src/lcs_mpiompO2.exe $$elem $$size $$omp 2; \
                    mpiexec -n $$np ./src/lcs_mpiompO3.exe $$elem $$size $$omp 3; \
                done; \
            done; \
        done; \
    done; \
```

The makefile itself should be correct, as the same file works for my colleagues. However, I don't understand why it's not working for me. There might be some missing components that need to be installed. The error message printed is:

unexpected i. mingw32-make: *** [MakefileW:60: execute] Error 255.

(I don't know if 'unexpected i' is the right translation because the language of my system is Italian)

Comment: You are running on Windows, and on Windows make is choosing to use the Windows shell.  The above loop is not written in Windows shell batch syntax, it's written in POSIX shell syntax (actually not just POSIX shell, but specifically bash because `{1..5}` is bash-specific syntax).  You'll either have to install a version of bash and get make to use that, or rewrite your script as Windows batch file syntax which would be extremely difficult.  In other words, that makefile is written for Linux or MacOS, not Windows.

Comment: I don't know if that's the problem. My colleague ran it on Windows and it worked. maybe he had something installed.

Comment: Is the first `for` at the left margin as you posted (which is wrong -- on _any_ platform) or indented as it should be (with a tab character)? PS: in a Unixy shell you don't need to split the pair into pieces yourself, just expand `$$pair` and shell standard parsing will split it for you.

Comment: It is definitely the problem.  Open up a Window terminal (not powershell, a cmd terminal) and enter the command `for i in {1..5}; do echo hi; done` and you'll get that exact error _i was unexpected at this time._  It's **definitely** because make is invoke the `cmd` shell.

Comment: The standard GNU Make will prefer to use a POSIX shell if it can find one on your PATH.  if it can't it will fall back to the Windows cmd shell.  If you want a specific shell without fallback you can set the `SHELL = ...` variable in your makefile then it will fail if that shell can't be found.  Your colleague clearly has a POSIX shell somewhere in their PATH.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 if the first line was not indented, the OP would see a completely different error so we can assume that it _is_ correctly indented with a TAB.

Comment: Just a general debugging hint: Because your code is supposed to be bash, I would first of all verify that `bash` is executed. You could create a `shelltest` target which does only do a `echo $$BASH_VERSINFO`. If you see a number to be printed, you can at least assume that you are in bash.